# Background image not 100% height when scrolling down page

Tags: html, css, background-image

My wrapper div contains a background image that ideally should have a height and width of 100%. For some reason after the initial size of the screen, anything after that height becomes a white space when scrolling down the page.

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto' , sans-serif;
}

.wrapper{
    background-image: url('./images/background.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML too?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose your problem is caused by the combination `height: 100%;` and `overflow: visible;`: You are fixing heigth to 100% (`min-height: 100%` won't do anything in that case), but overflowing content is still becoming visible, but isn't part of the "inital height", as you call it.

As a solution, you could keep `height: 100%;` remove `min-height: 100%;` and change `overflow: visible;` to `overflow: auto;`.